# I can't get my jquery to work in my wordpress site

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I was told that jquery was automagically included in wordpress from the get go, but I went ahead and included jquery in my functions.php. I'm trying to do a simple script that scrolls down to a div#id when a link is clicked.

I created this script:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  jQuery("#view-visibility").click(function() {
   jQuery('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: jQuery("#visibility").offset().top
   }, 2000);
  });
)};
```

I put the script in my own file, script.js, and added it to the functions.php:

`

```
function theme_js() {
  //parameters: 1.handle, 2.path, 3.array of dependents, 4.version specification, 5.load in footer? true or false
  wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js', '', '3.1.1', true );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap_js', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.4/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), '', true );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'my_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/script.js', array('jquery'), '', true );

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_js' );`
```

I still can't get it to work... I don't know what the deal is!! Should I be loading jquery in the head or before the body?

Link to my site
http://jakeford.io/pwi-project

Comment: Since you've instructed jQuery to use the `$` alias on the first line, you should use `$()` instead of `jQuery()` thereafter. Also, it is **always** helpful to share any error messages in your browser console.

Comment: I'm getting this error from the console, but I don't see where in the script it's talking about: script.js?ver=4.6.1:7 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Learn to use the developer tools in [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools) (or [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)) or [Chrome](https://developers.chrome.com/devtools/) or [Safari](https://developer.apple.com/safari/tools/) or [IE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673541(v=vs.85).aspx) to check for Javascript and other console errors.

In the console, I see `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ')' on line 9 of script.js.`

So try `});
});`

Comment: THANKS! I saw that error for the missing parenthesis but just needed a fresh set of eyes to find it. It is working :DDDD

Answer (score 2):

I have checked your site's `script.js` it does have syntax errors, try the code bellow:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(jQuery) {

  jQuery("#view-visibility").click(function() {
  jQuery('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: jQuery("#visibility").offset().top
  }, 2000);
  });
    jQuery('.my-slider').unslider({
      autoplay: true
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the fresh eyes guys. Time to take a break :D

Answer (score -1):

replace jQuery with $:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
  $("#view-visibility").click(function() {
   $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#visibility").offset().top
   }, 2000);
  });
)};
```

Comment: JQuery runs on compatibility mode on WordPress so using `$` directly will not work.

Comment: I tried the $ and this: jQuery(document).ready(function(jQuery) {
  jQuery("#view-visibility").click(function() {
  jQuery('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: jQuery("#visibility").offset().top
  }, 2000);
  });
)};